# Image processing in iOS. OpenGL, OpenCV, accelerate?

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es, accelerate-framework

I'm not expert in image processing and I need to include some complex image elaborations/readings into an iOS app I'm working on, so... I need to become an expert :P I wonder which is the best way to go when it comes to apply common image elaboration algorithms and maybe  also simple image editing (drawing simple shapes over an image like lines and quads). For my understanding I know that the candidate are 3: OpenGl, OpenCV or Accelerate framework (that can be used in conjunction with OpenCV)... I'm leaving out OpenCL since is something I'm not interested in at the moment.

Since I want to start learning more about the topic, I'm asking you: which library I should choose to implement image processing? is openGL to much vague maybe and I should prefer OpenCV over it? Is accelerate framework something that I can consider? 
I have started learning openGL and I know how GLSL works but I'm not proficient at all... so I can be considered new to all the listed libraries.

Note: I'm working in swift and I read that to adopt OpenCV it is better to use Objective-C++ wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is a 3D graphics rendering library. OpenCV is a computer vision library "focused on real-time image processing." GL creates images, CV processes them.ref :https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/136092-Whats-the-openGL-different-from-openCV

The openCV library has more than 2500 optimized algorithms, and can be used to detect and recognize faces, identify objects, classify human actions in videos, track camera movements, track moving objects, extract 3D models of objects, etc ref : http://opencv.org/about.html

Where as openGL is cross platform API is used to produce 2D/3D computer graphics using simple primitives. OpenGL ES is the lowest-level API used to program 2D and 3D in iphone. Also Cocos2D, Unity etc. are build using openGL.

Since in your case you are looking to draw lines on top of the images it should be possible to use opencv. The below link also explains how to draw lines on images. 
[Drawing fixed set of grid lines with opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318239/drawing-fixed-set-of-grid-lines-with-opencv)